# My post was labeled as not being focused and was closed. What do I need to fix the question?

Tags: discussion

This is the post.
[Fix Android 8 and 9 volume control so media and ringer are tied, notifications and assistant on own, and rockers mute without looking at screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221306/fix-android-8-and-9-volume-control-so-media-and-ringer-are-tied-notifications-a)

Perhaps I'm so angry and irritated at not being able to use my phone that it is a little difficult for me to be able to write a well formed question?

I suspect that there is no answer to my question other than "make your own custom rom"

There should be many ways to fix the problems, but none seem like they work. Other volume control apps that claim to be able to fix some of the problems no longer fix the problems on newer androids...  so I suppose I'm mostly asking if it is even possible to have working volume control on a non-rooted phone.

I'm probably going to install the developer kit and poke about, I'm discouraged that my attempt to have help find a direction to was shut down...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site focusing on Android end-users solving their issues. Consider taking a quick [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a short introduction on how Stack Exchange works in general.

Regarding the reason why the question was closed, ignoring the fluff/rambling, there are at least more than 1 tangential questions:

- Change the audio stream's volume for the ringer, media, notification, and assistant (Android provides many different audio streams, but it is up to the manufacturer/ROM on how to manage them)
- Adjust the Assistant's volume to the user's speech volume and customize its behavior on non-verbal activation (personally, I'm not sure if this is even possible at all)
- Silencing/muting the phone without looking at the screen (there are alternative solutions like automation and "do not disturb" mode)

While all of them are related to audio volume, solutions to one issue are possibly unrelated to other issues, making it unfocused (previously known as "too broad - multiple questions on a single post").

The problem with multiple questions on a single post is, answerers are expected to solve all the issues, preventing them from posting an answer if they only know the solution to an issue or two. Evaluating the answers also becomes difficult since an answer may contain a good solution to one issue but poor solution to another, while another answer provides vice-verse, making it a confusing situation for the voters and future readers.

Take note that developer-related questions (like asking for the API and how to build a ROM) are generally discouraged since the user-base of this community is Android end/power-users, but not necessarily developers.

The fix is to separate these issues into multiple posts, one focusing on a specific topic. Before posting a new question, please also search for existing questions to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I have already searched for and installed so many volume-control apps, and not of them work.

The question is mostly about if it is even possible with API, but it was closed on the programming version of this site, and they told me to post it here.

I could rephrase and indicate why it is a single question, but I don't know how to unclose the post.

I need granular control of volume control, and I couldn't find apps in the play store that do it.  I found ones that claimed to do it, but didn't.  Which makes me believe that Google made their OS unusable. I filed feature/bug requests there.

Comment: I'm pretty confused, because I just tried to edit the post to make it be those 3 parts... but they are all programming questions... and it wouldn't let me make even 1 narrow post. 

Is there a fork of stack exchange that manages  tangents in all their glory instead of ending them? I can't solve a problem in isolation.  That post was intended to be:  This is how volume controls need to work, how do I get there?